# How to reset user for rabbitmq management

Tags: rabbitmq

Using rabbitmq, we can install management plugin. Then we access via browser using `http://localhost:55672/` using guest:guest.
The problem is, I can not login anymore because i changed password and entered blank for role.

Is there any way to reset user for rabbitmq management?

Answer (score 210, accepted):

You can access the user-management with `rabbitmqctl` and use the command:

```
add_user {username} {password}
```

or more preferably maybe edit an existing user, or set the permissions for the new user with:

```
set_permissions [-p vhostpath] {user} {conf} {write} {read}
```

For example use the following commands: (it is important to perform these three steps even when creating a new user, if you want to be able to login to the UI console and for your programs to work without facing any permission issues)

```
rabbitmqctl add_user newadmin s0m3p4ssw0rd
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags newadmin administrator
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / newadmin ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

...to create a new administrator user with full access to the default / vhost.

You can find all this on the [RabbitMQ homepage](https://www.rabbitmq.com), and more specifically on this [page](http://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html)

Comment: thanks, i try this to set permission: rabbitmqctl set_user_tags khad administrator

Comment: @Superbiji you should consider converting this comment into an answer. I know it is old but this was the solution that worked for me.

Comment: ```set_permissions -p / newadmin ".*" ".*" ".*"``` this worked perfectly fine!! thanks

Comment: You should be logged in as root or use "sudo"

Comment: `"/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html" not found` received when I clicked on that "...this page" link. It's 27-July-2023 by the way.  : )

Answer (score 62):

The simplest way I found is to use this command to reset the password for any user in RabbitMQ

```
rabbitmqctl change_password <USERNAME> <NEWPASSWORD>
```

Comment: Thanks to this answer, I was able to figure out that passwords MUST NOT contain a `$` ... apparently.

Comment: Indeed, that took me a while to figure out: it is recommended to use an alphanumeric value with a very limited set of symbols (e.g. :, =). See RabbitMQ documentation: https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html#passwords-and-shell-escaping

Comment: Found this after ChatGPT advising me to delete and recreate the user and I was like "must be a better way..."

Answer (score 26):

This is specifically for aliveness test, but could apply to other apis as well

```
rabbitmqctl add_vhost statuscheckvhost
rabbitmqctl add_user heartbeat alive
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p statuscheckvhost heartbeat ".*" ".*" ".*"
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags heartbeat management

curl -i -u heartbeat:alive http://127.0.0.1:55672/api/aliveness-test/statuscheckvhost
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: MochiWeb/1.1 WebMachine/1.9.0 (someone had painted it blue)
Date: Thu, 21 Feb 2013 22:20:10 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 15
Cache-Control: no-cache
{"status":"ok"}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have RabbitMQ on a docker container, you can first

```
docker exec -it <YOUR_CONTAINER> /bin/bash
```

Then you can do

```
rabbitmqctl change_password <USERNAME> <NEWPASSWORD>
```

such as @samtoddler pointed out

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reset after this post. Thanks a lot.

rabbitmqctl add_user test password
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags test administrator

Then I went to browser console and login with this test account.
And from there I was able to reset pwd of admin account & guest account.