# RabbitMQ username & password

Tags: rabbitmq

Is it possible to recover the forgotten username and password which was used previously.

If it so please provide me your inputs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question deals with the quite similar problem: [How to reset user for rabbitmq management](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699873/how-to-reset-user-for-rabbitmq-management).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can change the password if we remember our username using the command

```
rabbitmqctl change_password username newpassword
```

if we execute the command above it will reset the password with the newpassword